# Swift classes are not loaded properly from the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have a project with several targets and several configurations: let's say `Target1/Target2` and `Debug/Alpha/Release` configurations. I also have a storyboard with some custom classes: let's say custom class `ViewController` which is an initial VC in my storyboard. I want to load view controller from the storyboard in the code like this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! ViewController
```

ViewController is a member of both targets. When I run the code above on the `Target1` - everything is ok on both configurations. When I run it on the `Target2` it's ok on `Debug`, but fails on `Alpha` with the message:

> Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file. Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10fbc71d0) to 'Target2.ViewController' (0x10b29cb88).

(in case of no `customModule` in the storyboard XML)

or

> Unknown class _TtC6Target19ViewController in Interface Builder file. Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x1083161d0) to 'Target2.ViewController' (0x103e6b840).

(in case when `customModule` in the storyboard XML doesn't match current target)

which eventually crashes the app.

Seems like it fails to add a proper namespace to the class name when loading it from the storyboard.

[Identity inspector looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AqJb.png)
In the storyboard XML there is:

```
<viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
```

If I specify the module in the storyboard inspector or directly in the XML for this view controller (customModule="Target2") everything works for both configuration on the `Target2`, but obviously fails on the `Target1`.

In the build settings for both targets: Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler - Options -> Default module inherits from `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME)`, which inherits from `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)`, which finally inherits `$(TARGET_NAME)`. If I print the TARGET_NAME in the runtime when I'm on `Target2 +  Alpha` (which doesn't work), I see the proper target name (`Target2` in this case). Which suppose to mean that module name should be properly added as a namespace to the ViewController when loading it.

When I created a sample project with the described configuration set, everything worked, which means that something is wrong in my `Alpha`-configuration in the real project, but it's almost an exact copy of `Debug` (excluding all the paths), which works.

After two days of poking and changing all this settings I'm out of ideas, so if somebody has ones, please fill free to share. I'll be more that appreciated.

Comment: Can do you share a simple project with this issue? Maybe something different in schemes?

Comment: @Bimawa As I mentioned when I tried to create a sample project with this configuration I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you tried this `let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController`

Comment: What do u have in configuration tab? http://take.ms/pNuW7 your Alpha configuration must have targets.

Comment: @dahiya_boy yep, the same result

Comment: And check your git status maybe you broken something?

Comment: Check your class in target membership?

Comment: @Bimawa In the configuration tab both configurations have all the targets. What specifically you meant to check in git?

Comment: @Dmitrii just get diff and check mb something broken?  Try delete `customModuleProvider="target"`

Comment: Do you migrate this project to new Swift version?

Comment: @Bimawa as I mentioned in the post the class is a member of both target.

Comment: @Bimawa it's Xcode 9.3.1 with Swift 4.1, the recent production one. (But checking it on the previous language version is a good idea)

Comment: @Dmitrii one more idea check why ur storyboard not contains `customModule="AppName"  `?

Comment: try it http://take.ms/b2o7t

Comment: @Bimawa by default xcode sets `customModule` to `customModule="Target1"`. As I mentioned if you set it to `customModule="Target2"` manually or via interface builder everything works for both configuration on `Target2`, but not for `Target1` anymore

Comment: @Dmitrii damn interesting, can you skype to me? bimawa account